# Certain websites not opening in mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi

I am connected to my university's internet. Internet websites open perfectly fine. However, university-related sites do not load. When I try to open those sites, it tries to load for a long time and then throws a "could not find server" error.  However, when I switch to a non-university internet connection, publicly hosted university sites (like the university homepage) load.

I am running macOS Catalina.

Although, I have found a hack that worked. If somebody has a proper solution that works or why this hack worked, let me know.

Comment: I imagine it's related to Domain Authentication. Assuming you're sitting in an AD (even on OSX), if you use a public DNS server on your machine (as a member of your AD), the TCP resolver will not be able to AD services to authenticate and gain the information that it needs... Without knowing more about your network, that's my best guess.

Comment: Can you expand the abbreviation AD?

Comment: Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I tried [these](https://youtu.be/fzZ7LHznWV4) solutions. However, they did not work.

The solution that worked: Removing the Google public DNS addresses from the DNS servers list. I had added them earlier for a VPN to work. 
[image: system-prefs]